# default.aspx renaming

Tags: visual-studio, 404, rename

I manage rip-off SharePoint team site. Some reason, I cannot rename default.aspx. 
If I rename default.aspx -> demo.aspx and I create new site collection, it gives me 404 error message. 
Also, if I change name default.aspx -> demo.aspx and I change it back to default.aspx, site collection throws 404 error message. Visual studio solution bust up some reason.

I have set Page scope to "Web".
[image: default.aspx content]

Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Module Name="HomePages" Url="" RootWebOnly="FALSE" Path="Files" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<File Url="default.aspx" Level="Published" Path="default.aspx" />
</Module>
</Elements>
```

Question is, how I can rename default.aspx or should I create new page?

If I need to create new site, example would be nice.

Comment: Rename the file, change Url and Path in the above XML. Problem will still be that you would have to set your demo.aspx as default page or navigate directly to the URL

Comment: If I rename file and I edit Elements.xml, how I can change default page in visual studio project? This is stupid, but I can not find it anywhere, where I can define default page.

Comment: Take a look here: http://nikpatel.net/2011/10/24/make-custom-landing-page-as-default-page-of-the-sharepoint-team-site-same-as-wiki-home-page/

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it didn't work. I also tried add this <Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="~/Home.aspx"/>

Comment: You call it demo.aspx above

Comment: Ye, I tried that but no luck... I started doubt myself already... I'm not sure is this even right path where visual studio puts Home.aspx, because when I deploy solution to server, visual studio prints this out: "Deleted file 'http://devwm/sites/EBIC/Files/Home.aspx' from server."

Comment: The Path in in your module above should be HomePages. You can alos use NavBarHome="True" on your File element

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you aren't renaming the page through the SharePoint interface.

1. Navigate to the page you wish to rename
2. Site Settings > All site content > Pages library
3. Right click the page
4. Select edit, rename the page/url in the box.
5. Save your changes